# When no user defined exception handler exists in Asp.Net MVC, does the worker process restarts for the first of the subsequent requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3

Assume I have no exception handler in my Asp.Net MVC application. It means all exceptions will be forwarded to the framework.

**The question is:**

When no user defined exception handler exists in Asp.Net MVC, does the worker process restarts for the first  of the subsequent requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When no user defined exception handler exists in Asp.Net MVC, does the worker process restarts for the first of the subsequent requests?

No, the worker process doesn't restart in case of unhandled exception. Of course there some kind of *special* exceptions such as OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException, ExecutionEngineException, ... which might bring the process down, but try throwing a normal `new Exception("foo");` in your controller action without a global exception handler and the worker process will stay alive.